# Howto limit timescaleDB queries to the used bucket size?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a **postgres timescaleDB** database with time series data.
The data in table flows was sampled roughly every **500ms**.

I need to get the data for **every 1 second**.
I tried to do it with time_bucket() function.

This was my test query:

```
    SELECT time_bucket('1 second', time) AS bucket, value AS val 
    FROM flows fl 
    WHERE
        fl.time > '2021-08-31 06:14:00+00' AND 
        fl.time <= '2021-08-31 06:18:00+00' AND 
        fl.sensor_id = 2 
    ORDER BY fl.time ASC;
```

The returned data looks as follows:

```
|bucket                  |val                  |
| ---------------------- | ------------------- |
| 2021-08-31 06:14:00+00 | 9.75071040883207    |
| 2021-08-31 06:14:00+00 | 10.008532745208633  |
| 2021-08-31 06:14:01+00 | 9.953632354528265   |
| 2021-08-31 06:14:01+00 | 9.833033340905137   |
| 2021-08-31 06:14:02+00 | 9.77205680132453    |
| 2021-08-31 06:14:02+00 | 10.197350449765523  |
| ...                    | ...                 |
```

As you can see, there are two rows for each bucket of one second. Values are coming from the samples that were collected every 500ms.

How to make sure there is **only one value per bucket**?
(In my case: One value every second)

I also tried an aggregation function (avg) on value, but that did not change the result.

Answer (score 3):

For time_bucket functions, in order to get the bucketing to work correctly, you will have to aggregate the `value` column in some way, and provide a group by statment. For example, something like this should correctly bucket the time,

```sql
    SELECT time_bucket('1 second', time) AS bucket, 
    sum(value) AS val 
    FROM flows fl 
    WHERE
        time_bucket('1 second', time) > '2021-08-31 06:14:00+00' AND 
        time_bucket('1 second', time) <= '2021-08-31 06:18:00+00' AND 
        fl.sensor_id = 2 
    GROUP BY bucket, sensor_id
    ORDER BY bucket ASC;
```

Hopefully this works for you!

disclosure: I am a part of the Timescale team

Comment: Thanks for replying, Miranda. Unfortunately I get : "ERROR:  column "fl.time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 9:     ORDER BY fl.time ASC;" So 'bucket' seems not to be sufficient for the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Ah, right, you will likely want to also represent your where clause arguments with the bucketed time, not the original time column.

Comment: I updated my example with the bucket statements in the where clause (and the order by)

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work for you!

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help! 